# is there a block ui jquery library that I can get via cdn?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, cdn

Pretty straightforward. I need to (well, I'd like to) use a library like `blockUI` but I'd really like to get it via CDN instead of pulling from my site. Linking directly to the blockUI file on github is giving me a 403 error, so I don't think that will  work.

Is there a big list of jquery libraries that are available via CDN?

Would I be better off just doing this via jquery native?

Is linking to github a good idea but I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know `blockUI` is not available from an official CDN like google or so.

google hosts these [Libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/)  and this [LINK](http://code.google.com/p/bainternet-js-cdn/) hosts libraries that dont have an official CDN provider. [BlockUI](http://code.google.com/p/bainternet-js-cdn/source/browse/trunk/js/jQuery+BlockUI+Plugin/2.39/jquery.blockUI.js?spec=svn6&r=6) is there also.

Comment: Ah, I had found that bainternet on google code but wasn't sure if linking to it was a good idea. Plus I wasn't sure how to link to it -- didn't try very hard though. After getting the link `http://bainternet-js-cdn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/jQuery%20BlockUI%20Plugin/2.39/jquery.blockUI.js` I see that it appears to be on a google CDN so it seems safe enough for my purposes.

Comment: Its not found now .`http://bainternet-js-cdn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/jQuery%20BlockUI%20Plugin/‌​2.39/jquery.blockUI.js` :(

Answer (score 4):

Since posting this question I have found some good **searchable** CDN resources:

http://jster.net/

http://cdnjs.com/

BlockUI is here:

`//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.blockUI/2.61.0-2013.06.06/jquery.blockUI.min.js`

Comment: I know this an old response but even now the version in cdnjs.com is not the latest version of BlockUI

Answer (score 1):

There is [Google Libraries API](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/libraries/devguide.html) with small amount of popular js libraries.

I think linking to github is bad idea because repo can contains unstable code (master). That depends how you do it and where you linking. Stable brach is better idea, but blockUI don't have one.

try this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/malsup/blockui/master/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="none">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $.blockUI({ message: '<h1>Just a moment...</h1>' });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok and which one of those libs in the google libraries does block ui? Doesn't look like any of them.

Comment: @jcollum None, or you can use jQuery to write your own small function to block ui ;) I just want to show you there is no cdn with a big list of jquery libraries. Use [aws s3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) to do your own CDN.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [RawGit](https://rawgit.com/), a free CDN for GitHub. Linking content directly from [GitHub.com](https://raw.github.com/malsup/blockui/master/jquery.blockUI.js) is not a good practice.

Prefer including your lib with a specific a [release tag](https://github.com/malsup/blockui/releases) :

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/malsup/blockui/2.70/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
```

Or with a [commit hash](https://github.com/malsup/blockui/commit/316f6e5d76a33266970778e80507149d9ef6a02d) :

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/malsup/blockui/commit/316f6e5d76a33266970778e80507149d9ef6a02d"></script>
```

And remember that a CDN can fail, even http://code.jquery.com, so include a fallback script in your site like this :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>if (typeof jQuery=== "undefined") { document.write('<script src="jquery.min.js">\x3C/script>') }</script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/malsup/blockui/2.70/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<script>if (typeof jQuery.blockUI === "undefined") { document.write('<script src="jquery.blockUI.js">\x3C/script>') }</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of blockUI is now available by CDN at: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.blockUI/2.70.0-2014.11.23/jquery.blockUI.min.js

You can see that one and other versions here:
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.blockUI

The cdnjs folks also take user contributions, so if there is something missing that you think should be there (like an out-of-date library or another useful JS library), you can fork their repo, update it yourself, and then submit a pull request. More on that here:
https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [CDNJs](https://cdnjs.com) website for any CDN JavaScript library.

For instance by searching for `blockui` I've found among other this CND:

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.blockUI/2.70/jquery.blockUI.min.js